# add column of listed keywords(strings) based on text column

Tags: r, string, dataframe

If i have a dataframe with the following column:

```
df$text <- c("This string is not that long", "This string is a bit longer but still not that long", "This one just helps with the example")
```

and strings like so:

```
keywords <- c("not that long", "This string", "example", "helps")
```

I am trying to add a column to my dataframe with a list of the keywords that exist in the text for each row:

df$keywords:

```
1 c("This string","not that long")    
2 c("This string","not that long")    
3 c("helps","example")
```

Though i'm unsure how to 1) extract the matching words from the text column and 2) how to then list them matching words in each row in the new column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can extract with `str_extract` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
df$keywords <- str_extract_all(df$text, paste(keywords, collapse = "|"))
df
#                                                text                   keywords
#1                        This string is not that long This string, not that long
#2 This string is a bit longer but still not that long This string, not that long
#3                This one just helps with the example             helps, example
```

Or in a chain

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate(keywords = str_extract_all(text, paste(keywords, collapse = "|")))
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe like this:

```
df = data.frame(text=c("This string is not that long", "This string is a bit longer but still not that long", "This one just helps with the example"))
keywords <- c("not that long", "This string", "example", "helps")

df$keywords = lapply(df$text, function(x) {keywords[sapply(keywords,grepl,x)]})
```

Output:

```
                                                 text                   keywords
1                        This string is not that long not that long, This string
2 This string is a bit longer but still not that long not that long, This string
3                This one just helps with the example             example, helps
```

---

The outer `lapply` loops over `df$text`, and the inner `lapply` checks for each element of `keywords` if it is in the element of `df$text`. So a slightly longer but perhaps easier to read equivalent would be:

```
df$keywords = lapply(df$text, function(x) {keywords[sapply(keywords, function(y){grepl(y,x)})]})
```

Hope this helps!